# Проверка на существование файла средствами с++

Tags: c++, windows, файлы

**Как осуществить проверку на существования файла в папке под ОС Windows?**
Желательно не пользоваться какими-то библиотеками помимо стандартных и `Windows.h`

```
std::ofstream outfile;
std::cout << "Enter full path to txt file" << std::endl;
std::string path_to_file;
std::cin >> path_to_file;
// далее должно быть ветвление в зависимости от существования файла
// если файл существует, дать выбор на перезапись или дозапись или создание другого
// если нет, то просто создать его
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX: [`stat()`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/stat) (в Visual C++ - [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=vs-2017)).

Стандартная библиотека - [`exists()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists)

Но учтите, что файлы - они такие, сейчас он есть, а через секунду нет :), да и всякие атрибуты и права доступа... словом, проверка, что файл существует, еще не гарантирует, что вы его сможете открыть и сделать с ним то или иное...

Так что в большинстве случаев лучше его просто пытаться открыть в соответствующем режиме, и проверять - получилось или нет.

Comment: К счастью, проверка делается для txt файлов, которые предполагаемый юзер и создаёт до этого куска. А вообще это требование обусловлено ТЗ по практическим работам моего учебного заведения

Comment: Значит, вы попадаете в меньшинство случаев :)

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно никаких библиотек, все делается стандартным С++ независимо от ОС (естественно без учета разного именования путей файла в разных ОС).

```
ifstream iff("filename.dat");
if(iff.bad()==true) cout<<"file is not present"; else cout<<"file is present";
```