# Можно ли отловить ошибку при использовании system("start ..")?

Tags: c++

Например, я хочу запустить стороннее приложение:

```
system("start name.exe");
```

Если файл не будет найден, то выйдет ошибка. При этом написано, что: `No-throw guarantee: this function does not throw exceptions.`
Т.е. отловить исключение нельзя? Можно ли тогда как-то обработать эту возможную ситуацию?

P.S. Извиняюсь, ошибка не прервет выполнение программы, но выдаст диалоговое окно с ошибкой и запись в консоль. Этого хочется избежать

Comment: Может есть смысл сначала проверить существование файла приложения? Например, [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946006/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81)

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов , есть конечно. В целом под этим вопросом я предполагал все возможные пути :) Спасибо за помощь, почитаю про это

Comment: *"this function does not throw exceptions"* - тут написано, что функция не кидает исключений. ¿Что вы собираетесь ловить? Хотите контроль над запуском - используйте boost.process.

Comment: А почему нельзя проверить возвращаемый функцией результат?...

Comment: @Harry проверить можно, но окно с ошибкой все равно появится. Я имел ввиду, отловить до его появления :) Мол не запустилось и не запустилось